# How to remove alpha from bulk images with AppleScript

Tags: bash, applescript

I have a bulk amount of images, of which i need to remove alpha from each. This is doable from Preview application, but the sheer amount of times i would need to repeat that is way too time consuming.

I have heard about AppleScript and made some feeble attempts at automating the process, currently to no avail.

i am using something like this and then starting a repeat, but it only allows me to loop through one direct folder (also i'm having troubles with menu bar items)

```
set fl to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/user/Documents/" as alias list
```

But i have multiple folders within folders which i wish to change an amount of images. the folder structure is like this:

Users/user/folder/ImagesRoot/

in inside ImagesRoot are 3 folders and one txt file. I want to specifically select 2 of the folders called "Icons" and "Screenshots". In "Icons" is 5 images. However "Screenshots" contains 3 subfolders, each with their own 5 images. (can be referred to as "Screensub 1,2,3")

Once receiving the list of images inside such folder, the process would be something like

```
tell application "Preview"
    open the image file 
    open the file menu
    open export...
    untick alpha
    press save
    press replace
    close window
end tell
Loop to next one
when looped through all in Icons folder, do all 5 images of each subfolder of screenshot folder
```

I am told that AppleScript is a good way to do this, but also that bash is a possibility?
However, i have 2% experience with applescript and maybe 4% of bash, and don't know how to approach it.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Preview doesn’t have the ability to change the alpha of a document, even if you [enable AppleScripting](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/stack-windows-top-each-other/applescript-preview-snow-leopard/). In an application that does support it, such as [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/), this is a fairly simple task:

```
on open imageFile
    tell application "GraphicConverter 9"
        open imageFile
        tell window 1
            set alpha to false
        end tell
        --save image as needed
    end tell
end open
```

You may find it easier to use Automator. The combination of *Get Folder Contents* with *Repeat for each subfolder found* and *Alpha Channel* set to *Remove* may be all you need. If you need to exclude some files, *Filter Finder Items* would do it.

If you want to use Preview, however, you may be able to use System Events. Something like:

```
on open imageFile
    tell application "Preview"
        open imageFile
        activate
        set filename to name of window 1
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Preview"
                click menu item "Export…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
                tell sheet 1 of window 1
                    --rename file
                    set value of text field 1 to filename & " Alpha Removed"

                    --uncheck alpha channel
                    tell checkbox 1 of group 1
                        click
                    end tell

                    --save
                    click button "Save"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end open
```

If you choose the assistive access route, you may find Apple’s help on signing applications useful: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914

Comment: When exporting, preview will have a tickbox for whether you want alpha (only if it detects it)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was looking in to graphics converter and it seems promisinh

Comment: Yes, I was making the assumption that all of the files you want to remove the alpha channel from have an alpha channel. If that isn’t true you may have to modify the script some. Also, for batch processing either with its own built-in batch system or with AppleScript, GraphicConverter is amazingly useful.